# Mvc 3 pass parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters

How can I pass the parameter `counter` to my `BindUnbind()` function?

```
 <div id="adver-list">
      @{
           var counter = 1;
           foreach (var adver in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.AdverImages)
           { 
               <div class="adver-image">
                    <img class="uploaded_image" src="@Url.Content(adver)" alt="advertisement"/>
                    <input class="hover-delete" id='@adver' type="button" onclick="DeleteAdver(this)"/>
               </div>
               counter += 1;
           }
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                     BindUnbind(counter, 1); // how to pass the counter from the above code?
                 });
            </script>
        }
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @ like you did before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindUnbind(@counter, 1);
});
</script>
```

Visual Studio might complain about a syntax error at the comma, but it will be fine at runtime.